# Does marking method pointer/reference parameters const really affect performance noticeably?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction

Setting aside the main reason for marking parameters as const - so you can't alter the referenced object by mistake - it is sometimes suggested this will be faster because the compiler knows the referenced object won't be modified.

However, is this actually likely to be true in a modern C++ compiler - and is the saving non-significant compared to the overhead of calling a method?

If so can someone explain at a lower-level what the differences would be, i.e. how the compiler can behave differently -  and perhaps give a concrete example where doing this would make a non-trivial difference?

Comment: This will never be true as long as `const_cast()` exists.

Comment: chandler carruth had a talk at boost con. he was pointing out that declaring things `const` is less helpful for performance than expected. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR34r7HOU14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern compilers are smart enough to see if a variable is going to be modified or not even if you don't specify it as `const`. For example, I just checked the assembler output of this code:

```
void foo( int & a )
{
    std::cout << a;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    foo(a);
}
```

with the `a` parameter being `int &` and `const int &`, and unsurprisingly the asm output was exactly the same in both cases.

In case of using a (const) reference vs passing by value, however, there will be a considerable difference. So use `const` for yourself and your colleagues, not for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> it is sometimes suggested this will be faster because the compiler knows the referenced object won't be modified.

If you have a const reference `r`, then the compiler only knows that the referenced object cannot be changed through `r`. But since const references also bind to mutable objects, const references aren't particularly helpful with regards to optimizations. Consider this classic counter-example:

```
void foo(const int& a, int& b)
{
    std::cout << a*a << '\n';
    ++b;
    std::cout << a*a << '\n';
}
```

Will this print the same number twice, or two different numbers? If `a` and `b` denote that same object, you will get two different numbers, even though we never modify `a` directly inside the function!

Comment: That's one great example, I should remember it for the future, thanks ;)

Comment: I think it would be different if `b` can't be an alias of `a`, let's says a `float&`

Comment: @Jarod42 Correct, but `foo` could call another function that might have access to the same `int`.